# How to highlight a taskbar item

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

In almost all messengers when your IM window is minimized to the taskbar, IM taskbar item changes color or gets brighter when you have a new message. I've been looking for any help on how to do this using .NET Winforms or WPF

Any code samples?

=====================================================================

EDIT: I used FlashWindow for my WPF window.

Ref: http://www.aeoth.net/blog/2007/04/27/flashing-the-window-in-wpf-c-2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to use the [FlashWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679347(VS.85).aspx) function. Basically, get a handle to the window, create a FLASHWINFO structure with the handle and how you want the window to flash (continuously, until it's opened, etc), and pass it into FlashWindowEx.

edit: Here's an [example](http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2008/04/19/3392.aspx) of how to do it in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I was still confused how to make it just highlight the taskbar item and not flash. Here's the code that ended up working for me (I feel pretty silly for missing setting count to 1, hopefully this will save someone else time).

```
Public Structure FLASHWINFO
  Public cbSize As UInt32
  Public hwnd As IntPtr
  Public dwFlags As UInt32
  Public uCount As UInt32
  Public dwTimeout As UInt32
End Structure

Private Declare Function FlashWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" (ByRef pfwi As FLASHWINFO) As Boolean

Private Const FLASHW_STOP As UInt32 = 0
Private Const FLASHW_CAPTION As UInt32 = 1
Private Const FLASHW_TRAY As UInt32 = 2
Private Const FLASHW_ALL As UInt32 = 3
Private Const FLASHW_TIMER As UInt32 = 4
Private Const FLASHW_TIMERNOFG As UInt32 = 12

Public Shared Sub Flash(ByRef thisForm As Form)   
  Dim flash As New FLASHWINFO With {
    .cbSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(flash),
    .hwnd = thisForm.Handle,
    .dwFlags = FLASHW_TRAY Or FLASHW_TIMERNOFG,
    .uCount = 1}
  'Leaving out .dwCount seems to work just fine for me, the uCount above keeps it from flashing

  FlashWindowEx(flash)
End Sub
```

Comment: This does not work. Setting uCount to 1 just flashes once. Still searching to just make the taskbar button orange, I don't want any blinking or flashing.

Comment: @Edwin I wonder if it's OS specific? I think I was probably either using Windows 7 (or maybe even Windows XP) back then.

Comment: I have discovered dwTimeout  is the time between flashes, not the rate at which it flashes. Setting it to 1 (millisecond) and uCount to UInt32.Max does the job now, the taskbar button is orange and keeps being orange. Maybe it's tied to the OS.